# How to extract values from CSV file without headers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x

I have a .csv file which contains one column of values (IDs).
When I use csv.Dictreader, each row is a dictionary wherein the key is the first value in the column (as it uses it as the header) and value is the ID present in the row.

I can't simply skip the first row (which I could have done had the file had a header) as I need the ID from the first row too. Manually adding a header isn't an option either.

How do I extract all the IDs from such a file as a list?
I'm doing the following right now:

```
def returnIDs(IDfile):# extract the IDs
    IDs = []
    with open(IDfile) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            for key, value in row.iteritems():
                IDs.append(key)
                IDs.append(value)
    return (list(set(IDs)))  # to remove the repetetive keys
```

But, I'm sure there's a more Pythonic way of achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the names of the columns you can specify them in the call to [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader). Then it won't use the first row as column names and you can get the ID from the row by name.

```
def returnIDs(IDfile):# extract the IDs
    IDs = set()
    with open(IDfile) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=['ID', 'other', 'fields'])
        for row in reader:
            IDs.add(row['ID'])
    return list(IDs)
```

Comment: that wouldn't have worked. The .csv file I have doesn't have headers (as mentioned in the question).

I got around to solving it by the following code:

def returnIDs(IDfile):
    IDs = []
    with open(IDfile) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
        for row in reader:
            IDs.append(row)
        IDs = [item for sublist in IDs for item in sublist]
    return IDs

Comment: It doesn't have headers, but you can provide a list of column names (even if you just make them up yourself). Then DictReader won't try to use the first row as a header row, and you can access the fields of each row by the names you specified.

Comment: Using csv.reader and getting fields by column number is fine too, but often it makes your code more readable to use column names.